# Use RegEx to wrap lines of text with string

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have:

```
bob\nwas\nhere
```

I would like RegEx to output:

```
*bob**was**here*
```

Where an asterisk was placed at the start and end of each line, and the new line character was removed.

I'm using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: How do you get away with boundry conditions in this question? I think if you ask a question like this aka "start/end", either this is a prank question or some diabolical test where the pre/post confabulation is designed to drive programmers mad.

Comment: Here is the answer `s/bob\nwas\nhere/*bob**was**here*/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var input = 'bob\nwas\nhere',
    re = /\n/g;

alert('*' + input.replace(re, '**') + '*');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TaUd7/2/)

Comment: I posted almost the same like you, but with re = /\n/g

Comment: @Fran: you're right - since I removed the `^` and `$` from my regex, I don't need the `m` flag anymore. Thanks!